# emails from gmail but response is gmail.readonly

Tags: gmail-api

I am trying to get the emails from gmail using `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly/?access_token='fdrt654vfdgfe6545`But in response I am getting `gmail.readonly`But the `System.HttpResponse[Status=OK, StatusCode=200]` is fine. Can any guide me is there anything I am missing out.

This I how I requested got auth but in the response I received access token

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
   var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
   po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
 })();
</script>



  <script type="text/javascript">
      (function() {
           var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
           po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
           var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
     })();

     var AuthStates = {google: null};

     function signinCallback(authResult) {
          if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {                  
            // Update the app to reflect a signed in user
            // Hide the sign-in button now that the user is authorized, for example:
            document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
            //alert(authResult['code']);
            console.log('code state: ' + authResult['code']);
            //console.log('authResult : ' + authResult[]);
            AuthStates.google = authResult;
            console.log('authResult 1 : ' + authResult['status']['method']);
            console.log('auth Result : ' + authResult['id_token']);
            //{!access_token} = authResult['access_token'];
            //{!code} = authResult['code'];
            connection(authResult['access_token'], authResult['code']);
          } else {
            // Update the app to reflect a signed out user
            // Possible error values:
            //   "user_signed_out" - User is signed-out
            //   "access_denied" - User denied access to your app
            //   "immediate_failed" - Could not automatically log in the user
            console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
          }
        }

  </script>


  <apex:outputPanel >
      <span id="signinButton">
          <span
            class="g-signin"
            data-callback="signinCallback"
            data-clientid="clientid"
            data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"                
            data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"
            data-response_type="code"
            data-redirect_uri="http://test-on.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/Gmail_inbox">
          </span>
    </span>
    <apex:form >
```

So as i got my access token from my request I can go directly for getting all information related to the logedin user. As I am getting all the information regarding the user I am trying to get all the emails related to him. Is I am doing right or I am wrong any place. I am very new with api and web service trying to learn. please do help me put out.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually making an HTTP GET call to that URL ( https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly/?access_token= ...)?  Isn't that just the auth scope *identifier*?

Once you have a valid Oauth2 token you can set in the Auth header then you can make HTTP requests to the API.  For example, to list messages see:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list

That has the URL to access (GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages ) then once you have the message IDs you can get the messages individually following: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get  (e.g. GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/ ).

Usually there are good client libraries for the Google APIs.  Not sure if that works for you, but see, for example:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/downloads

Comment: then what should be the url to extract all the emails from gmail as I do have the access_token.

Comment: I am updated my question please help me out of this.

Comment: To get a list of messages you could use the url:
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/
However the http request must include the access token as well. See https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground to see what the requests and responses look like.